# where clause and which clause

Tags: relative-clauses

Sometimes we can see where clause, but I can't find out the difference between where and which clause or if it can only use where clause in some specific situations. The sentences below is two examples I met lately, both of them in which I can't understand the inherent grammatical rules or where clause possesses a special meaning:

> Financial documents showing that you have sufficient funds available. These must clearly show that you have access to the funds, such as: where a third party (who is either in the UK or who will be legally in the UK at the time of your visit) is providing financial support to you e.g. a business, a friend or a relative, documents to show they have sufficient resources to support.

> Details of employment or studies where you have stated in your application that you are either employed or in full-time studies.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of "where" in both of these sentences is the same - "Where X is the case, please provide Y." This could not be replaced by "which," but it could be replaced by "if" - "Where you stated in your application that you were employed, please provide the details" could be rewritten as "If you stated in your application that you were employed, please provide the details."

Check out meaning 4b here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/where